# How to get page source for mobile NATIVE (without webviews) app using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios

How to get page source for mobile NATIVE (without webviews) app using selenium preferably in javascript?

Comment: are you talking about the inspector in selendroid?

Comment: @AnurajR, I was trying to do it with JS, so client.source() works perferct

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your chosen javascript client.

For example, with `wd`, you would use `wd.source();` as can be found from the wd api page: https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md

For webdriver-io, the command seems to be `client.source();`, as found from http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/source.html

If you want to use the selenium-webdriver, it seems that the command would be `driver.getPageSource();` as per http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html#getPageSource

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using webdriver-io and was trying to get it from getPageSource (which does not work) but .source works perfect. Thanks